# What is the reference potential when considering electric potential on a body in case of self capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

I was taking a lecture on self capacitance and the word 'potential of the conductor' came up. Now, self capacitance is for isolated conductors. From what reference is this potential measured?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other stated reference electric potential would be measured from the surroundings or “ground” (frequently available from the third wire on an electrical outlet).

Comment: Lets suppose we have the whole earth, from what reference will its potential be measure?

Comment: Pound a conducting rod into the earth (down to the water table if possible).